# Payroll program not displaying correct amount results

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a payroll program. The first base class is bonus the class should contain 2 public properties salesid and sales.
 Include a default constructor and a parameeterized constructor in the class.Also include a a getbonus method(function) that calculates a salespersons bonus using the formula sales*0.05
 create a derived class named Premiumbonus the derived clas getbonus mothod calculate the bonus as follows sales0.05 +(sales-2500)).01 also include a default and parameterized constructorin this derived class.
 if the sales is over 2500 use this

I feel like my math is off can someone please double check it? I need some suggestions and also i tried to debug and getbonus seems like it stays on 0 no matter what number i put but I get results in the calculated box.
 below is the code

Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Option Infer Off

```
    ' base class
    Public Class Bonus
    Public Property SalesId As String
    Public Property Sales As Double

    Public Sub New()
    _Sales = 0
    _SalesId = String.Empty




    End Sub
   Public Sub New(ByVal dblB As Double,
    ByVal strId As String)

    _Sales = dblB
    _SalesId = strId
   End Sub

  Public Overridable Function GetBonus() As Double
    ' returns sales 
    Return _Sales * 0.05
   End Function
  End Class


  ' derived class
   Public Class PremiumBonus
    Inherits Bonus

    Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New()
   End Sub

   Public Sub New(ByVal dblB As Double,
    ByVal strId As String)
    MyBase.New(dblB, strId)
    End Sub

     Public Overrides Function GetBonus() As Double
    Return MyBase.GetBonus + (Sales - 2500) * 0.01
   End Function
  End Class



    Private Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click
    ' calculates and displays a bonus

    Dim myBonus As New Bonus
    Dim myPremiumBonus As New PremiumBonus
    Dim Sales As Double

    ' if the sales are over $2500, instantiate a PremiumBonus object
    ' and then calculate the bonus
    ' otherwise, instantiate a Bonus object and then calculate the bonus

    If Sales > 2500 Then
        Double.TryParse(txtSales.Text, myBonus.Sales)
        Sales = myBonus.GetBonus

    Else
        Double.TryParse(txtSales.Text, myPremiumBonus.Sales)
        Sales = myPremiumBonus.GetBonus
    End If
```

Comment: craft a specific question like *when I enter X, the result is Y but it should be Z*  we are not code checkers and we dont do suggestions.  SO is about *answers* to *questions*.  See [Ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks anyway I fixed it I had the bonuses in the wrong spots

```
 Public Class Bonus
Public Property SalesId As String
Public Property Sales As Double

Public Sub New()
    _Sales = 0
    _SalesId = String.Empty




End Sub
Public Sub New(ByVal dblB As Double,
 ByVal strId As String)

    _Sales = dblB
    _SalesId = strId
  End Sub

Public Overridable Function GetBonus() As Double
    ' returns sales 
    Return _Sales * 0.05
   End Function
 End Class


 ' derived class
 Public Class PremiumBonus
Inherits Bonus

Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New()
End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal dblB As Double,
  ByVal strId As String)
    MyBase.New(dblB, strId)
End Sub

Public Overrides Function GetBonus() As Double
    Return MyBase.GetBonus + (Sales - 2500) * 0.01
End Function
 End Class

Private Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click
    ' calculates and displays a bonus

    Dim myBonus As New Bonus
    Dim myPremiumBonus As New PremiumBonus
    Dim Sales As Double

    ' if the sales are over $2500, instantiate a PremiumBonus object
    ' and then calculate the bonus
    ' otherwise, instantiate a Bonus object and then calculate the bonus

    If Val(txtSales.Text) > 2500 Then
        Double.TryParse(txtSales.Text, myPremiumBonus.Sales)
        Sales = myPremiumBonus.GetBonus

    Else
        Double.TryParse(txtSales.Text, myBonus.Sales)
        Sales = myBonus.GetBonus()
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your title:

> Payroll program not displaying correct amount results

and part of your description:

> getbonus seems like it stays on 0 no matter what number i put but I get results in the calculated box

I am pretty certain your question is "My output is zero regardless of input. What's wrong?"

---

I see in your code:

```
Dim Sales As Double
If Sales > 2500 Then
    Double.TryParse(txtSales.Text, myBonus.Sales)
    Sales = myBonus.GetBonus
```

You should probably look at populating `Sales` with a value prior to evaluating it, and it's probably a good idea not to use the same variable name in so many places, as it makes your code more difficult to read. You might try something like this:

```
Dim myNewBonus As Double
Dim Sales As Double
Double.TryParse(txtSales.Text, Sales)
If Sales > 2500 Then
    myBonus.Sales = Sales
    myNewBonus = myBonus.GetBonus()
```

Any if that still fails try using the debugger, or at least some strategically placed `MessageBox.Show(someValueIShouldCheck.ToString)`'s